# How can you set running applications (Session) to reopen on shutdown/restart?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, ubuntu-gnome, dconf

I've used the Dconf editor to set the auto save session to True however, this does not result in the session applications and windows to re-open when restarting or turning back on from a shutdown.

Am I missing something? Or is there a needed extra step to get my sessions, workspaces, and window arrangements to reopen when starting?